# Not disconnecting from FTP when NSConnection closing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp

I am using an edited version of Apple's [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code, specifically the "PUT" part. In it there is this method:

```
- (void)stopSendWithStatus:(NSString *)statusString
{
if (self.networkStream != nil) {
    [self.networkStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.networkStream.delegate = nil;
    [self.networkStream close];
    self.networkStream = nil;
}
if (self.fileStream != nil) {
    [self.fileStream close];
    self.fileStream = nil;
}
[self sendDidStopWithStatus:statusString];
uploaderbusy = 0;
}
```

Problem is that after the upload the application is NOT closing the connection. The code above is executed. Both IF statements are true and the code inside is executed.

This code:

```
    NSLog(@"%lu",[self.networkStream streamStatus]);
    [self.networkStream close];
    NSLog(@"%lu",[self.networkStream streamStatus]);
```

gives this output:

```
2013-03-03 17:50:26.460 Stockuploader[575:303] 2
2013-03-03 17:50:26.498 Stockuploader[575:303] 6
```

but the connection stays open and eventually times out. This is the log of the FTP server:

```
(000006)03/03/2013 17.50.27 - root2 (192.168.0.3)> 150 Connection accepted
(000006)03/03/2013 17.50.27 - root2 (192.168.0.3)> 226 Transfer OK
(000006)03/03/2013 17.52.28 - root2 (192.168.0.3)> 421 Connection timed out.
(000006)03/03/2013 17.52.28 - root2 (192.168.0.3)> disconnected.
```

Why is that?

if i CLOSE the program then the connection is instantly closed on the FTP. could it be that i have to deallocate the self.filestream? if so, how can i do it with ARC enabled?

**----UPDATE----**

I found that before i close the connection i have to send "QUIT" to the ftp server in order to let him know that i want to disconnect. but how can i implement the sending of "QUIT" command into the `SimpleFTPSample`?

Comment: `[self.networkStream close]` should close the connection. Which ftp server do you use?

Comment: i am using filezilla on another pc in the network. if i close the connection and then reopen the stream for a new file then it won't send username and password again. it will just start uploading the file. if the connection has closed then it should be re logging... streamstatus is returning 6, that means it is closed. but the FTP gets the disconnection as soon as i close the program or it times out. maybe i have to dealloc the stream but with ARC enabled i get a error.

Comment: I am not sure if you can reuse the same `self.networkStream` for a new connection, I assume that you have to create a new one. But that does not explain the close time-out. - (I cannot test this because I have a Mac and Filezilla Server seems to be Windows only.)

Comment: you can test this with any ftp server! the connections stays open..

Comment: do you have an idea about what i could do? is there a way to force deallocate an object with ARC?

Comment: The FTP protocol uses 2 connections, the data connection and the control connection. It seems that closing `self.networkStream` closes only the data connection, but the control connection stays open. I have no idea (yet) how to fix that. I do not think that it is an ARC problem. - When I have time I will try to investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Before* you open the connection, you have to set the `kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection` property to FALSE:

```
[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanFalse
                         forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection];
```

then the FTP stream closes both control and data connection when it is closed.

From the documentation:

> **kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection**
>   FTP Attempt Persistent
>   Connection stream property key for set and copy operations. Set this
>   property to `kCFBooleanTrue` to enable the reuse of existing server
>   connections; set this property to `kCFBooleanFalse` to not reuse
>   existing server connections. By default, this property is set to
>   `kCFBooleanTrue`.

Comment: I am also using Apple's simpleFTPSample. I am also having same problem as the "@Just me", but in my case, sometimes the uploading slows down due to bandwidth, and then if i hit "cancel uploading" to retry, it crashes, and takes to iPhone home screen.
on hitting "cancel upload", I am alsocalling the same code as that of shown in the question.

Comment: IT WORKEDDDD!!!! thank you soo much! as a side note: you must set this property BEFORE you open the connection else it wotn work! maybe add it to your post please for future Readers! thank you again! danke! grazie! gracias! whatever you Language is!

Comment: @Justme: Thank you for the feedback, I have added this information to the answer. - Btw. I figured this out by inspecting the source code http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128/FTP/CFFTPStream.c .

Answer (score 1):

Setting kCFStreamPropertyFTPAttemptPersistentConnection to kCFBooleanFalse did not close my lingering connection until I also set this (also prior to open):

```
[self.networkStream setProperty:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket];
```

Comment: hiya! could you please get in touch with me? my address is sharkyenergy X Hotmail dot com (replace X with @)